# Assign category to data based on range

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

In Excel, how would I take numbers from one column and assign them to a category in another? E.g., if I set ranges that correspond to certain words 1-10=Beginner, 11-20=Intermediate, etc. How would I take the values 2, 5, 9 19, 15, 3 and assign them to the appropriate categories in a corresponding column?

Answer (score 3):

If your numbers are in column A, you could enter the following in column B and fill down to assign a category to each.

```
=INDEX({"Beginner","Intermediate"},MATCH(A2,{1,11},1))
```

The key features of this formula:

1. An array of the categories is the first argument of the `INDEX` function. If you want more categories, include them here, comma-separated, each wrapped in quotation marks.
2. An array of the category range lower bounds is the second argument of the `MATCH` function. The number of values in the array should correspond to the number of categories. Each value is the lower bound of a defined category range.
3. `A2` is the address of the value you are categorizing (`2` is the first value in your example data).

[image]

If you were to expand your categories to include another category, e.g., "Advanced" for values 21+, the formula would be

```
=INDEX({"Beginner","Intermediate","Advanced"},MATCH(A2,{1,11,21},1))
```

Note that both arrays are expanded, but everything else remains the same.

Comment: How does this change as you add more ranges?

Comment: @HarteF. See my updated answer.

Comment: @LearnByReading Glad this helped! The best way to show appreciation for an answer on this site is to upvote it (by clicking the up arrow at the top-left of the answer. This awards reputation points to the answer's author and lets other visitors see at a glance which answers are most useful. And since you had a similar problem, you may also consider upvoting the question. For more info about the site, take a tour [here](https://superuser.com/tour).

Answer (score 2):

If your start range is cells A1, A2 with values 1 and 11; and end range is B1, B2 with values 10 and 20; and words are in C1, C2 with Beginner and Intermediate; and D column as 2,5,9,19, .... values, then enter this formula in E1:

```
=INDEX(C1:C2, SUMPRODUCT(--(D1<=B1:B2), --(D1>=A1:A2), ROW(A1:A2)))
```

This will enter Beginner in E1. Change D1 to 19 to see E1 change to Intermediate.

Comment: How does this change as you add more ranges?

Comment: @HarteF. fix the ranges in the formula. Or replace the static formulas with named ranges and when you expand the ranges, rename them. Look up Excel help for named ranges.